# Converting desktop application into server + browser application

Tags: java, json, jquery, web-applications, desktop-application

I am relatively new to web development, but I have some C++/Java experience. I have got the following conversion to do:

**Current:**
Desktop Application (Automation Software) developed in C# that communicates with remote PLC (Controller that overlooks different sensors in realtime) using TCP Sockets over the Web.

**My Idea:**
Convert the application into a server side software that will still communicate with the PLC over TCP/Socket. And use a browser to operate it, so the remote site can be monitored and controlled from any computer in our Intranet (possibly Tablets in the future).

**Motive for doing it:**
We had a computer fault which left the operators without control.

**The new app:**

I am planning on writing the server app using Java and OOP (so far no problem). And use HTML/CSS/Javascript for the WebApp and AJAX to update the page. 
But I am still lost at how can I transport all this data between them in a proper and decent manner. I have read about SOAP and JSON in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532566/to-soap-or-not-to-soap-that-is-the-question). Although, I am not sure if I need to use them at all, is it a good solution to use either JSON or SOAP? Or is there any other solution that you may recommend?

Cheers,
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is for defining public APIs that are published on the internet for other people to use, which does not seem like your use case.  It is not particularly awesome to have to deal with it from inside a browser either, although there are javascript SOAP-client libraries.  There is also going to be a fair bit more overhead on the server side parsing and validating XML than de/serializing between JSON and POJOs.

JSON is much easier to deal with in a browser, being natively understood and all that.  Everything you need is built into the core of jQuery, no dependence on plugins that may have unknown levels of future support.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Although this brings a new question (which I didn't think before). Do you know if using JSON and AJAX I could have refresh rates minimum of 100 ms on the webapp?

Comment: You may want to look into a technology called WebSockets or Comet.  It is an alternative to ajax-polling that is built into HTML5 and supported by jQuery plugins in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider skipping the development work to convert your app into a server-side software and just go for a third party solution, I suggest you take a look to Thinfinity VirtualUI.

"...offers a GUI remoting solution for in-house Windows desktop
developments, allowing them to be delivered as Windows/HTML5 dual-platform applications
simply by adding one line of code.
These Windows applications can keep their standard desktop environment behavior and,
alternatively, be accessed remotely from any modern web browser in a multi-user,
multi-instance fashion when hosted on a Thinfinity VirtualUI Server environment."

https://www.cybelesoft.com/docs/thinfinity_virtualui_whitepaper.pdf